# Ethernet driver installation from terminal (Wired and Wireless connection on Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 10 Dual boot is not working)

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, drivers, ethernet

I am new in Linux. When installing dual boot the Ethernet connection in Ubuntu is not working (even though when only Ubuntu or only Windows installed everything works fine). The wireless connection does not work from other reasons. After investigation, I think I have to install the driver manually via terminal. Part of the problem is that I have quite a new motherboard (**motherboard asus z170i pro gaming**). In order to do so I run following code to figure out exactly which driver I need:

`lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`:

```
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V [8086:15b8] (rev 31)
     Subsystem: ASUSTek Computer Inc. Device [1043:86cd]
```

So I guess this is a thingy which I need to make working. I google it and downloaded OS Independent driver from [this website](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/82186/Intel-Ethernet-Connection-I219-V).

Afterwards, I moved the file via USB to Ubuntu system but I failed to install it or find some online help how to do so.

Comment: You should download the Linux driver first off.

Comment: The driver for that device should be included in the Linux kernel out of the box (go to https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/E1000E.html and search for `15b8`). Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result so we can have a closer look at the issue? Thanks.

Comment: @Marek do you have any update for a solution on this? I am having the same problem